# share() vs ReplaySubject: Which one, and neither works

Tags: angularjs, caching, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to implement short-term caching in my Angular service -- a bunch of sub-components get created in rapid succession, and each one has an HTTP call.  I want to cache them while the page is loading, but not forever.

I've tried the following two methods, neither of which have worked.  In both cases, the HTTP URL is hit once for each instance of the component that is created; I want to avoid that -- ideally, the URL would be hit once when the grid is created, then the cache expires and the next time I need to create the component it hits the URL all over again.  I pulled both techniques from other threads on StackOverflow.

**share() (in service)**

```
getData(id: number): Observable<MyClass[]> {
    return this._http.get(this.URL)
        .map((response: Response) => <MyClass[]>response.json())
        .share();
}
```

**ReplaySubject (in service)**

```
private replaySubject = new ReplaySubject(1, 10000);
getData(id: number): Observable<MyClass[]> {
    if (this.replaySubject.observers.length) {
        return this.replaySubject;
    } else {
        return this._http.get(this.URL)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let data = <MyClass[]>response.json();
                this.replaySubject.next(data);
                return data;
            });
    }
}
```

**Caller (in component)**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getData(this.id)
        .subscribe((resultData: MyClass[]) => {
            this.data = resultData;
        },
        (error: any) => {
            alert(error);
        });
}
```

There's really no need to hit the URL each time the component is created -- they return the same data, and in a grid of rows that contain the component, the data will be the same.  I *could* call it once when the grid itself is created, and pass that data into the component.  But I want to avoid that, for two reasons: first, the component should be relatively self-sufficient.  If I use the component elsewhere, I don't want to the parent component to have to cache data there, too.  Second, I want to find a short-term caching pattern that can be applied elsewhere in the application.  I'm not the only person working on this, and I want to keep the code clean.

Answer (score 3):

Most importantly, if you want to make something persistent even when creating/destroying Angular components it can't be created in that component but in a service that is shared among your components.

Regarding RxJS, you usually don't have to use `ReplaySubject` directly and use just `publishReplay(1, 10000)->refCount()` instead.

The `share()` operator is just a shorthand for `publish()->refCount()` that uses `Subject` internally which means it doesn't replay cached values.

Comment: I might have been unclear (I'll update the post with this information), but the `share()` and `RelaySubject()` code is in the service, while the caller code is in the component.